# How do I change the swpath value?

Tags: javascript, pwabuilder

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<head>
<script type="module">
   import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwaupdate';
   const el = document.createElement('pwa-update');
   document.body.appendChild(el);
</script>
...
</head>
```

I tried to apply a PWA to my site according to this document (https://github.com/pwa-builder/pwabuilder-web/blob/V2/src/assets/next-steps.md). However, that didn't work as intended, and looking at my browser's debug tools I found that I needed to change the value of `swpath`.

I tried various methods to change the value of `swpath`, but failed, and the repository only states that the value of `swpath` exists, but does not tell me how to change it. I was wondering how to change the value of `swpath`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
...
<script type="module">
   import 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@pwabuilder/pwaupdate';
   const el = document.createElement('pwa-update');
   el.swpath = "/pwabuilder-sw.js";
   document.body.appendChild(el);
</script>
...
</head>
```

I solved the problem with the above code.

Comment: Please provide more information about how you solved the problem (e.g.: explain your code).

Comment: Added `el.swpath = "/pwabuilder-sw.js";` between `const el = document.createElement('pwa-update');` and `document.body.appendChild(el);`.